# VBA Excel add in -- Initialize global variables on load -- not in workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating an excel add-in that connects to functions and formulas set up on an API. 
To use the API functions the user needs to log in and receive a Token.

The Token is a global variable that is referenced whenever calling an API function.

This add in will be used by many different workbooks so i'm trying to make it as easy as possible for the user to connect.

At the moment i have a function that connects and stores the details in global variable so they only have to log in once. But every time they close and re open they have to log back in by calling the function and passing in the details.

**Is there a way of accessing initialize workbook from an add-in?**

**an on-load equivalent?**

**Or getting add-in Functions to run on start up?** without the user having to set up macros or custom functions, they can just add in and auto connect with their details.

```
'Is their an equivalent of
Sub New() /  Sub OnLoad()
   Initalize()
End sub
```

---

I don't want the user to have to worry at all about whats going on behind they just have to load up the page with their username and password in defined cells or a function that references the username and password that even when the page is set to manual calculations it will recalculate on load.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Rather than storing the token as a global, store it as a defined name, which is persistent. Then simply evaluate the name every time you need the token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than storing the token as a global, store it as a defined name, which is persistent.

```
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add "Token", sToken
```

Then simply evaluate the name every time you need the token.

```
 sToken = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).[Token]
```

Comment: I like the idea, it has potential if i set up a button to click to log in which references the Username and Password cells. But I cant Use ThisWorkbook.Names.Add in a function. The problem i still face is that i might only let tokens last a day for security reasons. So it would be a daily log in. Would there be a way of automating the log in. Which is why i wanted to know if there was a way of calling a onload from an add-in.

Comment: There is no such event. Regarding the age of the token, you can store when the token was obtained in the comments of the defined name, like so:

Comment: Then, if too old, get a new token.

Comment: When you say function, do you mean UDF? Because there is no reason that you cannot do this from a function.

Comment: As I understood, the OP wanted that once the user is logged in and closes the WB, he will not be prompted again for login *even if he opens another WB*. Did I misunderstand the requirement?

Comment: @A.S.H Correct, but with the caveat that this is Add-in code.

Comment: But then why not store this information in some persistent space, i.e. registry, file, DB, etc.

Comment: That's an option, but the Names collection of the Add-in is equally persistent.

Comment: When i try to call ThisWorkbook.Names.Add the same way you described it escapes the UDF with no reason. I assumed it was because it was changing something outside of the functions scope. I'm quite new to Excel VBA but I've had a similar problem referencing other cells from functions. I have only been able to do that through buttons is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Something as simple as this doesn't work `Function SetToken(newToken As String) As String
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add "Token", newToken
SetToken = "New Token is set to: " + ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).[Token]
End Function` it breaks just after its set.

Comment: @ExcelHero Ah ok, I see :)

Comment: No, if it is a true UDF being called from a worksheet formula, then you are correct, but why would you do that. A VBA function called from another VBA procedure does not have this restriction and it CAN change the workbook.

Comment: @ChristopherDermody-Lawrence How are you calling the sample function you just posted? I just tested it here and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks very much for all the help. How do you think i should call the functions? a button that takes in defined cells? or is there an easier way to  send the username and password to the UDF add-in

Comment: @ExcelHero I'm probably calling it all wrong. I literally call in in the cell =SetToken("fdsfsdfdfa")

Comment: Ahh... Yes, that is the problem. Don't call from a cell formula. You can call it from any VBA procedure. It can be called from a button click, but probably the best is to call it from the add-in's Workbook_Open()

Comment: Perfect that's exactly what i was looking for thanks

Answer (score 2):

If anyone was curious. I found that you can initialize the global variables with something similar to OnLoad().

```
Private WebAddress As String

Sub Auto_Open()
    WebAddress = "www.stackoverflow.com"
End Sub
```

Can be in a module, and is called when the workbook opens.